# Loading animations triggers on scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm working on a one page website that has a loading animation similar to that one.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5

It works great but it triggers also on scroll animation that don't works.
How can i fix it?

I'm using that library for on scroll animation
https://jjcosgrove.github.io/jquery-aniview/

here's a working example  codepen.io/beer_baron/pen/qBBroRB

Comment: please include [mcve], I don't understand what you mean by *it triggers also on scroll animation that don't works.*

Comment: I need some animations like that page https://jjcosgrove.github.io/jquery-aniview/.Without the loading they are working, with the loading the animation doesn't perform and the html is already visible

Comment: again, without [mcve], no one could knows what's wrong.